# How to store the indices into one variable

Tags: python, string, indexing

This is my code:

```
sub = ['great to have','good to have']
my_string =''' 

s =""    
for i in sub:
    ii = my_string.lower().find(i)
    my_string[ii:]
```

How to store the indexes into variable `s`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would want a *list* of indices? You could define s as a list, `s=[]`, and use `s.append(my_string.lower().find(i))`

Then if you are really trying to just build the indices into a single string you could use

```
','.join(map(str, s))
```

To join the elements in the list with a comma, while converting the values to strings.

Also if you don't want to include -1 for elements that are not found, you could check for that in your loop.

```
s =[]
for i in sub: 
    index = my_string.lower().find(i)
    if index != -1:
        s.append(index)

indices = ','.join(map(str, s)) 
print(indices)
```

If you ran the above code with your inputs, your output would be

```
92
```

**EDIT**: Clarification that you aren't looking for the index, but the text trailing a found substring. You would need to add the length of the substring to the index and use `:`

```
s =[]
for i in sub: 
    index = my_string.lower().find(i)
    if index != -1:
        s.append(my_string[index + len(i):])

matches = ','.join(map(str, s)) 
print(matches)
```

This output would be

```
: - DevExpress Experience (in Angular 2+ or AngularJS) - Strong DBD understanding and experience (set-based artifact design, performance tuning, modeling)
```

Comment: i am looking for this out put  s = '': - DevExpress Experience (in Angular 2+ or AngularJS) - Strong DBD understanding and experience (set-based artifact design, performance tuning, modeling)''

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, is that your desired output? The indices would be the location of where the found substring is, like you stated

Comment: the sub string is (great to have) after this sub string we have to store the values in a string variable